# Can't we use all the mining/processing power to calculate useful stuff?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-technical-details

When computers are mining now, they're actually trying to break nonsense codes. Can't all that processing power be used to do better things with like 
[gridrepublic](http://www.gridrepublic.org) etc.?

Comment: Note that these days, much mining is done by dedicated hardware such as ASICs, which are designed for a single computational task only and are not useful for other work.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it could be it's just not the type of [proof of work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) algorithm that was used. Some crypto-coins have since been implemented that are somewhat useful, such as [Primecoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primecoin).